# Syntax error when I type in textbox doing RowFilter

Tags: c#, sql, dataview

I'm trying to search a database in gridview. When I type anything in the textbox I get this error:

> syntax error missing operand before 'like' operator

This is the code:

```
private void txtGrid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = ""+cbGrid.Text + " like '%" + txtGrid.Text + "%'";
    gridPlayers.DataSource = dv;
}
```

I thought that it might be the `'`, but I have searched and read all other relevant questions I could find.

Comment: What is the content of cbGrid.Text?

Comment: It could be that the function is firing off when `cbGrid.Text` is an empty string.

Comment: You'll want to build a parser for that string so that you can scrub any "illegal" characters for your RowFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `cbGrid.Text` is an empty string. If there is a missing operand, it's because it was not provided (it was blank).

A possible solution is to make sure to only run the filter if the value is not empty, or give it a default value.

```
private void txtGrid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbGrid.Text))    
    {
        // only run when not empty
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = ""+cbGrid.Text + " like '%" + txtGrid.Text + "%'";
        gridPlayers.DataSource = dv;
    }
}
```

Comment: You´re completely right, the error mostly ocurred because the combobox started empty... great solution for that.

However, the error still occurs when I search in one of my three rows, they are all three nvarchar(30)

Comment: And I just found my spelling error in my adding that row to the combobox, and problem fixed...